# Get disjoint sets from a list in R

Tags: r

Given a list:

```
foo <- list(c("a", "b", "d"), c("c", "b"), c("c"),
            c("b", "d"), c("e", "f"), c("e", "g"))
```

what is an efficient way to get a list that contains the disjoint sets of its content?

Here I want to obtain:

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

[[2]]
[1] "e" "f" "g"
```

The solutions I have managed to come up with seemed overly complicated and slow (I'm working with a largish list (4000+ elements) that contain up to hundreds of elements).

Thanks!

---

**Solutions benchmarking**

Thank you all for your input. The igraph approach is really nice. I did some benchmarking of the proposed solutions and using igraph with @flodel suggestion is efficient. The example here (`iGrp`) has 3170 elements.

```
> microbenchmark(igraph_method(iGrp), igraph_method2(iGrp), iterative_method(iGrp), times=10L)
## Unit: milliseconds
##                    expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
##     igraph_method(iGrp) 6892.8534 7140.0287 7229.5569 7396.2458 8044.9796    10
##    igraph_method2(iGrp)  381.4555  391.2097  442.3282  472.5641  537.4885    10
##  iterative_method(iGrp) 7118.7857 7272.9568 7595.9700 7675.2888 8485.4388    10

#### functions used

igraph_method <- function(lst) {
    edg <- do.call("rbind", lapply(lst, function(x) {
        if (length(x) > 1) t(combn(x, 2)) else NULL
        }))
    g <- graph.data.frame(edg)
    split(V(g)$name, clusters(g)$membership)
}

igraph_method2 <- function(lst) {
    edg <- do.call("rbind", lapply(lst, function(x) {
        if (length(x) > 1) cbind(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1)) else NULL
    }))
    g <- graph.data.frame(edg)
    split(V(g)$name, clusters(g)$membership)
}

iterative_method <- function(lst) {
    Reduce(function(l, x)  {
        matches <- sapply(l, function(i) any(x %in% i))

        if (any(matches)) {
            combined <- unique(c(unlist(l[matches]), x))
            l[matches] <- NULL        # Delete old entries
            l <- c(l, list(combined)) # Add combined entries
        } else {
            l <- c(l, list(x))        # New list entry
        }
        l
    }, lst, init=list())
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to approach this sort of problem is to build a graph where nodes are the values in your list and edges are whether those values have appeared together. Then you're just asking for the connected components of that graph. The `igraph` package in R makes this pretty easy. First, you'll want to build a data frame with the edges:

```
edges <- do.call(rbind, lapply(foo, function(x) {
  if (length(x) > 1) cbind(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1)) else NULL  
}))
edges
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "a"  "b" 
# [2,] "b"  "d" 
# [3,] "c"  "b" 
# [4,] "b"  "d" 
# [5,] "e"  "f" 
# [6,] "e"  "g"
```

Then, you can build your graph from the edges and compute the connected components:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(edges, directed=FALSE)
split(V(g)$name, clusters(g)$membership)
# $`1`
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "e" "f" "g"
```

For reasonably large problems, this approach seems to be modestly faster than an iterative approach:

```
values = as.character(1:2000)
set.seed(144)
foo <- lapply(1:4000, function(x) sample(values, rbinom(1, 10, .5)))
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(josilber(foo), lundberg(foo))
# Unit: milliseconds
#           expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
#  josilber(foo) 251.8007 281.0168 297.2446 314.6714  635.7916   100
#  lundberg(foo) 640.0575 714.9658 761.3777 827.5415 1118.3517   100
```

Comment: That's one heck of a workaround. Although I've had some trouble with large graphs in iGraph.

Comment: @flodel connected components can be computed in O(|V| + |E|), where V is the vertices of the graph and E is the edges. Each element of the 4000-long list contributes n(n-1)/2 edges, where n is the length of that element. Therefore, this approach is polynomial in the input size. I'll leave comments on its speed to benchmarking; unfortunately the OP provided no benchmark code.

Comment: You can keep `edges`'s size down by only using `function(x) if (length(x) > 1) cbind(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1)) else NULL` inside the `lapply`. And make the graph undirected.

Comment: @flodel thanks -- that is really helpful and improves the asymptotic runtime of the procedure to `O(c)`, where `c` is `length(unlist(foo))`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an iterative approach, building a list for the result, and combining elements as they are seen together:

```
Reduce(function(l, x) {
    matches <- sapply(l, function(i) any(x %in% i))

    if (any(matches)) {
        combined <- unique(c(unlist(l[matches]), x))
        l[matches] <- NULL        # Delete old entries
        l <- c(l, list(combined)) # Add combined entries
    } else {
        l <- c(l, list(x))        # New list entry
    }
    l
}, foo, init=list())
## [[1]]
## [1] "a" "b" "d" "c"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "e" "f" "g"
```